# Whether JS / Jquery can be used for cross platform application development?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whether JS / Jquery can be used for cross platform application development ?

We are working on a small web application which we are expecting to integrate with any other Web Applications ( Either developed on .Net or Php or Ruby-rails ).

On developing an application on JavaScript/ Jquery will make it cross platform supportable ?

Comment: JS/Jquery is the front-end rite, what alternative do you have?

Comment: [Yes](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk), [yes](https://cordova.apache.org/) and [yes](http://phonegap.com/). Just depends which tool you'd prefer to use.

Comment: @Iceman, Project is in Inception. As of now, i dont have an alternative.